# TensorFlow attribute capitalization, e.g. tf.constant vs tf.Variable

Tags: tensorflow, attributes, capitalization

I'm pretty puzzled by TensorFlow attribute capitalization.
From https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started:

```
node1 = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype = tf.float32)
```

If you change capitalization on either it throws the same AttributeError, so one would guess both are attributes and should be capitalized equally.

Thanks for helping to understand any intricacy I overlook!
G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.constant()` is a function (i.e. an operation)   https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/constant_op/constant_value_tensors#constant

whereas

`tf.Variable` is a class.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable